# What does 在来自中 (zài láizì zhōng) mean in 在来自中、俄、美、英、韩等五国, ...?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading a news article (about Trump canceling his meeting with Kim Jong Un, 25 May, 2018) on a flight:

[image: Newspaper snippet]

I don't understand the use of 在来自中 in the second sentence:

> 当天早些时候，**在来自中**、俄、美、英、韩等五国20多名记者的见证下，朝鲜炸毁了丰溪里核试验场的坑道，。。。
>   <sub>dāngtiān zǎoxiēshíhòu, **zài láizì zhōng**, é, měi, yīng, hán děng wǔ guó 20 duō míng jìzhě de jiànzhèng xià, cháoxiǎn zhàhuǐle fēngxīlǐ héshìyànchǎng de kēngdào, ...</sub>

I translate this to:

> In the early morning, with [???], Russia, the USA, England, South Korea, and 5 other countries, and 20+ journalists to witness, North Korea blew up Fengxi's nuclear test facility tunnels, ...

I don't understand what [来自](http://dict.cn/%E6%9D%A5%E8%87%AA) (láizì) = "come from" is doing here, nor what [中](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%AD) (zhōng) = "within" is achieving in this sentence.

**Question**: What does 在来自中 mean in 在来自中、俄、美、英、韩等五国, ...?

Comment: 来自 is a complete word, which anything following would be the source of 来自.

Comment: ... under witness of 2 dozens of journalists from China, Russian, USA, UK, South Korea...  (來自 means "from" , e.g. a reporter from USA).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

中 is the short form of 中国 here.

中 = China

There’s a 顿号 (、) after 中 so you can tell that it is part of a list, that would aid your deciphering methods letting you know it’s not a phrase with the words in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it more understandable when it's translated into: *under the witnessing of 20+ journalists coming from 5 countries including China, Russia,....*

> 在来自中、俄、美、英、韩等五国20多名记者的见证下

The sentence has a small issue here. 等 should be deleted because 中、俄、美、英、韩 altogether already reached to 5 countries. The correct sentence should be:

> 在来自中、俄、美、英、韩五国20多名记者的见证下...

Or

> 在来自中、俄、美等五国20多名记者的见证下...

**Edit**:

As fefe pointed out, the original sentence is also correct 在来自中、俄、美、英、韩等五国20多名记者的见证下. But you can remove 等 as well. It might be about the personal stylish.

Comment: “等” can be used when all are listed.

Comment: @fefe You might be right. The dictionary on my phone has a sentence to support your point. *长江、黄河、黑龙江、珠江等四大河流*. But in my opinion, 等 means *so on and so forth*. If all has been listed, why do we need verbosely to add 等 at the end. Maybe, this is not about right or wrong, but a stylish thing I think.

Comment: It's an indication that the listing ends here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a pair of parentheses can help you understand the sentence:

> 在来自（中、俄、美）等五国。。。